# NameError: name 'urllib2' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I am currently building a webscraper and I need to catch url exceptions. My code sample is the one below.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

Try:
  //some code


Except urllib2.HTTPError:
  pass
```

Comment: Your sample code is not valid Python; `try` and `except` must be entirely *lowercase*.

Answer (score 12):

You only imported the name `urlopen`, not the `urllib2` module itself.

Import the exception too and refer to it directly:

```
 from urllib2 import urlopen, HTTPError

 try:
     # ...
 except HTTPError:
     pass
```

Alternatively, import just the module, but then also use `urllib2.urlopen()`:

```
 import urllib2

 try:
     # ...
     response = urllib2.urlopen(...)
     # ...
 except urllib2.HTTPError:
     pass
```